# How to make background music played? AS3.0

Tags: actionscript-3

I just started to learn Action Script, and need for the project to insert background music.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var snd = new Sound();
var src = new URLRequest("music.mp3");
var sndChannel;
var sndTrans = new SoundTransform();
sndTrans.volume=0.5;
snd.load(src);
snd.addEventListener("complete",completeListener);
function completeListener(e){
    sndChannel = snd.play();
    sndChannel.soundTransform=sndTrans;
 }
```

sndTrans.volume -this volume.
0.5 - 50% of this volume. 
If you need maximum volume accordingly writes 1
Good luck in your studies!